# How to sum a (float,float) type elements in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Here is my code 
Now it works with Float -> Float -> Float but i can't make it work with my defined "Complex" type.  
I would like to make it look and work like this.

```
   add :: Complex -> Float
```

I think it's like chaning only a few words but i can't figure it out. Thanks for your patience.

Here is my code

```
type Complex = (Float,Float)

add :: Float -> Float -> Float
add a b = a+b


xor :: Float -> Float -> Float
xor a b = a*b
```

Comment: `add (a,b) = a+b`?

Comment: Already tried, says this

ERROR - Type error in application
*** Expression     : addS 2.0 3.0
*** Term           : addS
*** Type           : Complex -> Float
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c

Comment: Sounds like you tried to call `add` with its old signature `add :: Float -> Float -> Float`. If you are calling the new `add`, it should be something like `add (2.0,3.0)`, _not_ `add 2.0 3.0`.

Comment: Oh really :D if you leave an answer i will vote it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined `add` like this:

```
add :: Float -> Float -> Float
add a b = a+b
```

You could apply `add` to `Complex` objects like this:

```
uncurry add (2.0, 3.0)
```

uncurry "converts" a function of type `(a -> b -> c)` to a function of type `((a, b) -> c)`